# why is there difference in the name string of "__Method" and "Method"

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4

I've implemented a nested properties class. When i was working with it i used the `__getattr__(self, name)` method and i noticed that when I referred to a method in my class name `def MethodName(self)` it would pass a string to the `__getattr__(self,name)` method with `name = MethodName` This makes sense for me.

However if i changed my `def MethodName(self)` to `def __MethodName(self)` the string passed is `name = _ClassName__MethodName`

Why the addition of the `_ClassName` ?

Comment: Google "name mangling Python".

Comment: Thank you. didn't know what to look for.